# Get total of Vue component computed instances

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, computed-properties

Please see my jsbin here http://jsbin.com/puxefasohu/1/edit?html,js,output I have a "Receipt" component that contains a computed function of 'total'. In the parent component, I am trying to get a total of all the 'Receipt' component's instances of this computed value to get my 'Grandtotal', but I am unable to communicate the Component instances to the parent. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using [Custom Events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Custom-Events).  It will decouple your "Receipt" component from having to know that it's parent "needs" a grand total.  Just announce changes in your Receipt total and let your parent listen for those changes.